# Match Varbinary(max) with another Varbinary(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, binary

i have a table with one binary column. that contains 0x00010100000101010101......00 column datalength is 35040,
i am prepare this data like

`@Jobbyte =  COALESCE(@Jobbyte , 0x) + Cast ((Case When Sum(A.bit) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)as binary(1))`

i have to compare this binary data with another binary data and get the matching binary count. both the binary data has equal length of data

Please look below image, their is 2 binary data Binary1 and Binary2 i want to compare both binary data and get Sum of matching binary data. only one condition is when binary2's single bit is 0x01

[image]

Last Row is indicate 0 = No Match, 1 = Match and last column is Sum of Last row (4)
Please suggest me how can i compare , it's better if you can post a query

**Update 1**

---

i am doing with 2 function and try to resolve but it's take to much time while execute with 10000 record, execution time for 1 record is 50 Millisecond

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_BinaryToTable]
(   
    @BinaryData VARBINARY(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    Select  ((N.Number / 96) - (Case (N.Number % 96) when 0 Then 1 else 0 end))+1 As [FNNoDay],
            (Case (N.Number % 96) when 0 then 96 else (N.Number % 96) end) * 15  AS [FnMinutes],
            SUBSTRING(@BinaryData,(N.Number),1) AS [FNBIT]
    from    Numbers N 
    Where N.Number between 1 and (DATALENGTH(@BinaryData))
)
---------------------------------------------------------
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetPercentage]
(
    @JobValue int,  
    @CandidateBinary VARBINARY(max),
    @JobBinary VARBINARY(max)
)
RETURNS Decimal
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RValue Decimal;

    SELECT  @RValue = SUM(cast(JB.FNBIT as int))            
    FROM    dbo.Fn_BinaryToTable(@CandidateBinary)   CB,
            dbo.Fn_BinaryToTable(@JobBinary) JB
    WHERE   CB.FNNoDay = JB.FNNoDay
      AND   CB.FnMinutes = JB.FNMinutes
      AND   JB.FNBIT = CB.FNBIT
      AND   JB.FNBIT = 0x01

    Return ((@RValue * 100)/ @JobValue);
END
--------------------------------------------------------
Declare @Jobbyte varbinary(max);
Declare @JobValue int; 

Select @Jobbyte = JobBinary from Job;
Select @JobValue = count(*) from dbo.Fn_BinaryToTable(@Jobbyte) Where FNBIT = 0x01

----Select @JobValue = Sum(Cast(FNBIT as int)) from dbo.Fn_BinaryToTable(@Jobbyte)
set statistics time on
set statistics io on

select cid,dbo.fn_GetPercentage(@JobValue,cal,@Jobbyte) from eCal

set statistics time oFF
set statistics io oFF

----------------------------------------------------------
```

- A Numbers table contains only one  int field  that contains 1 to
  99999 value
- 96 use for a 15 Minute interval of one day (24* (60/15))

Comment: i am update question with one solution but it will take to much time to execute

Answer (score 0):

Please look at next code. It's generate rows and compare segments of both strings:

```
with q as (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar(max), a ,2) a, -- convert 'a' bin data to varchar
        CONVERT(varchar(max), b ,2) b  -- convert 'b' bin data to varchar
    FROM
        (
            SELECT -- a, b - test bin data
                Cast (1 as binary(1)) + Cast (0 as binary(1)) + Cast (1 as binary(1)) a, -- 01 00 01
                Cast (1 as binary(1)) + Cast (1 as binary(1)) + Cast (1 as binary(1)) b  -- 01 01 01 - 2 matches
        ) k
)

select
    --*, substring(a, x + 1, 2), substring(b, x + 1, 2)
    sum(case when 
        substring(a, x + 1, 2) = substring(b, x + 1, 2) -- is block equals
    then 1 else 0 end) sum_of_all_pair_equals
from
    q
        join
    ( -- generate 99999 rows for getting 2 chars block from staring a, b
        select
            x * 10000 + y * 1000 + z * 100 + k * 10 + l as x
        from
            (select 1 x union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) x,
            (select 1 y union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) y,
            (select 1 z union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) z,
            (select 1 k union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) k,
            (select 1 l union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) l
    ) x
        on (
            x between 0 and len(a) - 2 -- start from 1 to len - 2
            and x % 2 = 0 -- get every even x
        )
```

this query must be faster, but I have not tested it for perfomance:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(30); -- a bin string
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(30); -- b bin string
DECLARE @itersLeft INT; -- iterations count
DECLARE @i INT; -- counter
DECLARE @outCnt INT; -- result match counter

SELECT
    @a = CONVERT(varchar(max), a ,2), -- convert 'a' bin data to varchar
    @b = CONVERT(varchar(max), b ,2)  -- convert 'b' bin data to varchar
FROM
    (
        SELECT -- a, b - test bin data
            Cast (1 as binary(1)) + Cast (0 as binary(1)) + Cast (1 as binary(1)) a, -- 01 00 01
            Cast (1 as binary(1)) + Cast (1 as binary(1)) + Cast (1 as binary(1)) b  -- 01 01 01 - 2 matches
    ) k
    ;

SET @i = 0; -- init counter
SET @outCnt = 0; -- init result counter
SELECT @itersLeft = LEN(@a) - 2; -- setting max iterations counter

WHILE @i <= @itersLeft
BEGIN
        if substring(@a, @i + 1, 2) = substring(@b, @i + 1, 2) -- compare data
            SET @outCnt = @outCnt + 1; -- increase counter if equals

        SET @i = @i + 2; -- increase counter by block size
END

SELECT @outCnt result; -- selecting result
```

Comment: Hi - Вадим Зинчук , i am try to pass binary instead of string but result is only 1 , can you suggest me how can i use for binary data and this suggestion is working for up to 35040  length of binary data

Comment: Hi - Вадим Зинчук- thanks for your solution, this is working as we expect but it's create a performance issue,when i am execute with one record the execution time is a 9 Sec. and i have to execute query with 10000 record so it's a timeout setuation

Comment: Greetings, Chirag, please look at new query in my answer.